# How can I work with a 4GB csv file?

Tags: tool-request, data-format, programming, csv

What's the best way to access a 4GB csv file?

I would like get a 'cut' of this open data set: Full Replacement Monthly NPI File, [available here](http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html).

Specifically, I want only the rows for hospitals; though, one might want the rows for healthcare clearing houses, or home health agencies, etc.

The unzipped NPI file is 4.8GB, which is too large for my desktop applications. It is an interesting barrier to open data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to open the file with the suggested programms from the link (TextPad and UltraEdit). Few weeks before, I open a csv file of 3.5GB with excel.

Comment: Data like this *shouts* 'database'. Pull it into any RDBMS you have available (they all have tools), 4GB is no issue for them. Drop the columns you don't need or make views to only the required columns.

Comment: There are some good answers regarding python - if you only read one line at a time, you can load any size file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17444799/2327328

Comment: We frequently use bash or other shells in unix/os x for basic file manipulation.  If you only need to subset it, commands like "grep", "cut" and "sed" can get you a long way.  If you want to work with it extensively and frequently, a SQL database might be a better shot.  I don't know if SQLite would satisfy your requirements, but there are also heavy duty tools like mysql and postgresql that are open source.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for Pandas in Python. Check it out!

Comment: Depending on how often you are doing it, maybe look at a provider for NPPES data like NPIViewer.com. I have seen a lot of organization try to handle it in-house and if you are doing it often it can be much cheaper and easier to subscribe to a place that already has it handled.

Comment: hi rob, thanks for the input, but your solution is not an open data solution as it costs money. don't want to discourage you from participating here, your comment is valuable and helpful, it just serves the community better if it were posted as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I have started working on a desktop app todo just this - handle big CSV files, automatically reload from disk and NOT scroll to the top, basic editing and row based cut and paste....Given that this is 2017 and everything is online, would anyone find this of use? I have tried other tools and they don't this as well, or are difficult to use for data analysts...

Comment: the source file URL does not work

Comment: Try [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv). A command like `xsv select "Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1" inputfile.csv` will extract a column of data, much faster than the excellent csvkit. (I don't have enough reputation yet to answer below)

Answer (score 65):

This is the kind of thing that the [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) was built for:

```
csvgrep -c "Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1" -r '^282N' npidata_20050523-20131110.csv > hospitals.csv
```

> csvkit is a suite of utilities for converting to and working with CSV, the king of tabular file formats.

A little more efficiently, you could do:

```
zcat NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Nov_2013.zip | grep 282N | csvgrep -c 48 -r '^282N' > hospitals.csv
```

Comment: Indeed it works line-by-line on the CSV, so handles large files extremely well.

Comment: However it's csvcut tool is for stripping off columns. It doesn't appear to have a clear way to extract rows.

Comment: `csvgrep`is for matching rows.

Comment: Is there cygwin version of csvkit, or windows binaries I can use? I prefer not installing Python if necessary.

Answer (score 26):

On Windows, [SweetScape 010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) is the best application I am aware of to open/edit large files (easily up to 25 GB). It took around 10 seconds on my computer to open your 4 GB file (SSD):

[image]

More such tools: [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159521/395857)

Comment: Can this query rows using criteria?

Comment: [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) is totally free, not crippleware, and supports regex search and replace, shows hidden characters (cuz I get some bad data from customers), opens large files, and much more. I think it can also run Javascript on the current open tab but that requires programming.

Answer (score 17):

As you're only taking a portion of the file, you may be able to use simple tools to subset it before processing.  That may get it down to a reasonable size to work with.

If you're working on a posix (ie, unix-like) system, you can use shell commands to reduce the file:

`zcat -c`*filename*`| grep`*(pattern to match hospitals only)*`>`*outputFile*

This lets you extract the lines without uncompressing the larger file on disk.  (with today's systems, drive speeds are often a limiting factor, so working with the data compressed can be more efficient if you have sufficient CPU).

If it were tab-deliminated, pipe-delimited, or fixed-width, you can also reduce the columns with the unix `cut` command ... but it's hit-or-miss with CSV, as it'll break horribly if there are commas in strings:

`zcat -c`*(filename)*`| grep`*(pattern to match hospitals only)* `| cut -d, -f`*(list of fields)* `>`*outputFile*

Comment: If you are using Windows, you can install something like http://www.cygwin.com/ and you'll be able to use the commands above (cat, grep, etc)

Comment: This is no good when there are new-lines inside cells. Use tools design for CSV.

Comment: @DRead : quite true.  I'd personally argue that if you've got newlines in your cells, CSV might not be the best format to store your data.  Unfortunately, we're a bit at the mercy of what other formats people publish their data in.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a downside of CSV. However I don't think the existence of new-lines should deter you from CSV as there are usually more important reasons to using it. Would you say the same for data with commas quoted in cells? That makes it a pain for tools like sed and awk doing work on cells, in a similar way. I think we just need to accept that although CSV has many advantages because of its simplicity, its not as simple to parse as many would believe and you need to use tools and libraries.

Comment: In addition to your answer, I found this related tutorial http://schoolofdata.org/2013/12/05/working-with-large-text-files-finding-uk-companies-by-postcode-or-business-area/

Comment: See also: Playing With Large (ish) CSV Files, and Using Them as a Database from the Command Line: EDINA OpenURL Logs http://blog.ouseful.info/2011/06/04/playing-with-large-ish-csv-files-and-using-them-as-a-database-edina-openurl-logs/

Answer (score 15):

you can connect to the file with sql and run your analysis from there.

i have written extremely detailed r code (r is free and open source) about how to work with the nppes from your laptop here:

http://asdfree.com/national-plan-and-provider-enumeration-system-nppes.html

if you have never used r before, check out http://twotorials.com for a crash course

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 11):

Others have mentioned way to pull apart this file incrementally.  It seems to me like you are also commenting on use of resources for a large file.  For some solutions you can incrementally read the compressed file uncompressing as you go and feed it through the csv module.  For example in python with gzip'd input you would do this by:

```
import csv
import gzip

with gzip.open("test.csv.gz", "r") as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
        pass  # do something with the row
```

You could do the same thing for zip archives with zipfile.

If this data is coming from across a network you can pay very little or sometimes get performance improvements by not copying and then uncompressing it.  It can cost you less to pull it across the network compressed (smaller) in pieces and operate on it then it does to pull it across in bulk, uncompress it, and then read it.  It also doesn't use up local storage resources.

Answer (score 10):

There are streaming CSV parsers, that only look at a small window of the file at a time.

Node is a particularly stream-friendly language and ecology, so here a few Node streaming CSV parsers:

https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-csv
https://github.com/koles/ya-csv
https://github.com/lbdremy/node-csv-stream

Comment: With Node.JS streams it doesn't really matter *how* big the file is! The streams keep reading and writing from / into buffers. Its like buffering a video on YouTube.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, there is also a software called **Delimit** ("Open data files up to 2 billion rows and 2 million columns large!") http://delimitware.com  For instance it can split, sort and extract only some rows or columns.

Comment: Can confirm - this is really fast

Comment: I recommended Delimit above. Now that it is faster and more csv able, I also recommend Emeditor https://www.emeditor.com

Answer (score 7):

Load the file into PostgreSQL database table  with a Copy statement.  This will give you the full  capabilities of SQL syntax, plus the ability to index columns for faster access.

For complex queries  you have a optimizer that a can figure out the fastest way  to access the data. PostgreSQL has smarter I/O than  most applications it will detect sequential read access and read-ahead to pre-load data into memory.

Results can be viewed in Excel or other spreadsheets by accessing the data via an ODBC driver.

You can access to PostgreSQL via several Cloud Services like Heroku or AWS.  It would be  good cloud project to create a new machine instance, install PostgreSQL and copy the data to the instance. Then use the Postgres COPY command  to load the data and then access the data with a  PostgreSQL client application from your desktop.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is not really useful for non-programmers, but if could manage some programming in perl, the [Parse::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CSV) module is especially designed for this task.

From the doc:

> It provides a flexible and light-weight streaming parser for large,
>   extremely large, or arbitrarily large CSV files.

Perl is usually very good for data mining tasks.

Comment: I have used Perl to read 2GB text files before. Usually I use tab-delimited data as I don't need a module to process it. In fact, Perl is so fast reading text files that I convert large XLS files to tab-delimited text files before reading them. Perl can also read line-by-line for ginormous files. But I just read the whole 2GB file into an array at once.

Answer (score 5):

I have used utilities such as (g)awk to readlarge file such as this record by record. I the extract the required information from each line and write it to an output file. For windows users (g)awk is available in cygwin. I have also used python to achieve the same result. You could implement this process in most programming languages.

Comment: It's somewhat AWKward when there is a weird character encoding or quoted commas or new-lines in the CSV. Best stick with a CSV-oriented tool.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in short, [Talend Open Studio for Data Integration](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration) is an ETL.

It can be used for many use cases, including data migration, files processing, etc.
You can easily build jobs using a visual editor to combine specialized connectors (read CSV files, select rows corresponding to your criteria, write result to one or more files or directly to a database, and more). The possibilities are endless because there are more than 800 connectors.

At the end, TOS generates a java application which can be launched from the designer or for the command line (Windows or Unix).

Hope this helps.

Comment: or you can even run the job from TOS without compiling the java.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Windows, I can't sing the praises of [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) high enough.  It allows you to query files in a wide variety of formats (mostly log formats as that's what it was meant for, but XML and CSV are valid).  You query the file with a surprisingly complete SQL syntax, and you can even use it to import an entire file directly into an SQL database very easily.

It's extremely fast, too.  I've used it to process 5 GB of IIS log files and a query as complex as `SELECT DISTINCT cs-username, cs(User-Agent) FROM .\*.log where cs-username is not null` took about 2 minutes to complete running on my laptop.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with Python, there are a couple of options:

Something simple like

```
with open('in_filepath', 'r') as inf, open('out_filepath', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        # do some processing, e.g, .split(',')
        if criterion: # check if you want this row
            outf.write(line)
```

would work, since it reads the file iteratively, not all at once.

Alternatively, there is a `csv` module in the standard library of Python that works quite similarly:

```
import csv
with open('my.csv', 'r') as inf, , open('out_filepath', 'w') as outf:
    csvreader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvreader:
    ...
```

There is also a new nice Python library called blaze, which is has been designed to work with a large number of large CSV files. Here is a nice tutorial about how to use it for this purpose: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/blaze.pydata.org/notebooks/timings-csv.ipynb

Comment: I also like the python solution, but for working with CSV files, it may be safer to use the 'csv' module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. One reason is that without 'csv', splitting on the delimiter doesn't work if the field contains the delimiter.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in certain cases it might be the better choice!

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to parse the 6GB NPPES file and here is how I did it:

```
$ wget http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_July_2017.zip
$ unzip NPPES_Data_Dissemination_July_2017.zip
$ split -l 1000000 npidata_20050523-20170709.csv
$ add headers...
$ python parse.py
$ load *.tab files to the database
```

---

The code for the parse.py script used to extract some columns:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv

files = [
    'xaa.csv',
    'xab.csv',
    'xac.csv',
    'xad.csv',
    'xae.csv',
    'xaf.csv']

usecols = [
    "NPI",
    "Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)",
    "Provider Business Mailing Address City Name",
    "Provider Business Mailing Address State Name",
    "Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code",
    "Provider Business Mailing Address Country Code (If outside U.S.)"]

for f in files:
    print("Parsing file: {}".format(f))
    df = pd.read_csv(f,
                     engine='c',
                     dtype='object',
                     skipinitialspace=True,
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                     usecols=usecols,
                     nrows=None)
    df.rename(columns={
        'NPI': 'npi',
        'Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)': 'business',
        'Provider Business Mailing Address City Name': 'adr_city',
        'Provider Business Mailing Address State Name': 'adr_state',
        'Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code': 'adr_zip',
        'Provider Business Mailing Address Country Code (If outside U.S.)': 'adr_country',  # noqa
    }, inplace=True)
    out = os.path.join('out', "{}.tab".format(f))
    df.to_csv(out, sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am a big fan of [tad](http://tadviewer.com/) which crunches these kind of files easily.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can uncompress the online archive, your best approach might be to:

1. split the uncompressed 4GB csv into smaller files and then
2. extract the information interested,
3. spool these rows into output-csv files and finally
4. join those output-csv files back into one csv file for further processing. You can then use this file e.g. with SQL databases, Open-/Libre-/MS-Office, Statistical tools etc.

Depending on the OS you are using, there are a series of open source tools available to split / join large files or tools already installed.

**MS Windows:**
you will have to install a tool or use a script (e.g python) to do the splitting. If you search Google for "splitting csv files" you will find quite a selection.

*Alternatively you could also use a live CD/USB stick with e.g. Ubuntu on it (see the Ubuntu web site for how to create one) and then use the approach below.*

**Linux / Unix:**
Use the split command:
e.g. `split -d -l 10000 source.csv tempfile.part.`

this will split `source.csv` into files containing 10'000 lines each and named `tempfile.part.00`, `tempfile.part.01` ...

You can use the `join` command to join the multiple output files from your selections together into one csv file (either by naming the files and piping them into one file or by joining all files within a folder into one output file - please check the `join` manual pages or online how to do this in detail).

Comment: I haven't used this way before, but I have a question for you. If I use split in Windows or Linux, the split doesn't need to load the whole csv file in RAM? If my file is really big, can split handle it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'split' is no good if there are carriage returns inside cells. Stick to tools designed for CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [nitroproc](http://www.nitroproc.com). It's currently a beta version I think, but allows to sort/summarize/filter/etc. It's free.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck in R (without resorting to fancy packages) of reading CSVs up to and beyond that size. The nice thing about getting it in RAM, if you can swing it, is very fast manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some processing on a large csv file,
the best option is to read the file as chunks, process them one by one, and save the output to disk (using pandas for example).

If you want to explore the file and you are looking for free tools,
you can use [Power Query add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) for Excel or [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/) log explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to be able to read / query the data, you could use:

- [`csvs-to-sqlite`](https://github.com/simonw/csvs-to-sqlite) to convert import the CSV file into a SQLite database. You can do this as a mapping into a single database table (for example: `csvs-to-sqlite myfile.csv mydatabase.db`), or you can use the `csvs-to-sqlite` tool to split the data into separate tables automatically linked by foreign key relationships;
- query the SQLite database directly, or publish a simple HTML form that supports faceted and/or form driven searching / filtering as well as a form that lets you enter and run arbitrary read-only SQL queries, using[`datasette`](https://github.com/simonw/datasette/). For example, `datasette serve -p 8899 mydatabase.db` to serve the `datasette` browser on localhost port 8899.

As an added benefit, the `datasette` service also provides an API that allows you to run arbitrary SQL queries on the data via a simple URL and retrieve the data as JSON.

A query can also be used to export just the data you want as a smaller CSV file ([`datasette` - CSV export](https://datasette.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csv_export.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Gigasheet, which is relatively new, now allows you to upload and work with a 1 billion row CSV file in a browser-based, excel-like interface. The full details are here: https://www.gigasheet.co/post/open-large-csv-file, and nice video showing the interaction is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0ZC73oi-WM.

It's pretty straight-forward. You'll need to create a (free) account at gigasheet.co, after which you can upload your file and interact with it immediately.

Disclosure: Since posting this answer, I joined the Gigasheet team