# How do i import a 2gig csv file into R and be able to work with it on my PC?

Tags: machine-learning

Importing data into the R programming environment. I've tried imorting the data set with read.csv() but its telling me it cannot import vector of more than 500mb.

Comment: seems to be more of a programming question (--> stackoverflow). Also, see this question https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1256/1511 (in general, don't load columns you don't need, and avoid special packages when the data model is simple)

Answer (score 1):

Load the csv into a database first then use odbc to  read the fields / records you need into your data frame